# MYSQL generate 5 random characters (1-9, A-Z) for 200 rows

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way to automatically create a table(id,password) with 200 rows, and generate 5 digit password (1-9, A-Z)for the 200 rows with php/mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For generating the 5 digit password in MySQL you could use something like the following:

```
SUBSTRING(conv(floor(rand() * 99999999999999), 20, 36), 1, 5);
```

And if you want to solve everything on database level you can take a look at the loop syntax provided by stored procedures.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE doiterate(p1 INT)
BEGIN
  label1: LOOP
    SET p1 = p1 + 1;
    IF p1 < 10 THEN
      ITERATE label1;
    END IF;
    LEAVE label1;
  END LOOP label1;
  SET @x = p1;
END;
```

Example from: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/loop.html

Comment: I edited my answer above - Should be better... What do you think? (I'm not that experienced with calculating entropy, so just tell me when I'm wrong ;))

Comment: What about the pseudo random issues?

Comment: Why converting *from* base 20?

Comment: You're asking too much here, sorry. I just saw that it won't create a random string every time depending on the chosen from and to bases. But I'm really not that fit in converting numbers to a different base.

Comment: @LouisH. Hence the name pseudo random.

Comment: @TigOldBitties Thanks for the info. Is that a problem just with the mysql random generator or most random number generators in general? Do you know a good article I could read something about the issue?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator Google is your friend. http://www.random.org/ to read on true randomness and the w31rd ways it's implemented.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function generate($length, $chars = '') {
    if (!$chars) $chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890';
    $ret = '';
    for ($x=0;$x<$length;$x++) {
        $ret .= $chars[rand(0,strlen($chars)-1)];
    }
    return $ret;
}

for ($x=0;$x<200;$x++) {
    Sql::exec('INSERT INTO users (id,password) VALUES (NULL,?)',generate(5)); // just replace with your own function to execute SQL
}
?>
```